# Why is Google Form stuck on "Updates made after release"?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-classroom

I was trying to find a way to ask help for Google Forms so I hope this is an acceptable place (official forums > no answer).

I am using Google Forms to create quizzes for my students but when I correct them I often find myself being unable to return them as, instead of the button "Release Score" I see "Updates made after release".

Does anybody know what this is about and how to work around this?
Google Help has no mention on this and my question on this topic has gone unanswered for more than a month.

Thank you

EDIT: adding pictures of what I am seeing and of the Quiz settings, as requested in one of the answers.
[image: What I see]
[image: Quiz settings 1]
[image: Quiz settings 2]
[image: Quiz settings 3]

Answer (score 1):

The marker has the option of editing the question and/or the answer of one or more individuals or all respondents. This can be done *before* or *after* grades are released.

If it is done *after* respondent grades are released, the message `Updates made after release` will appear to the left of the "Release score" button. It is really just a warning, and does NOT hide the "Release score" button, or stop it from being clicked.

---

**Quiz completed, scores NOT released**

[image: Completed not released]

---

**Quiz completed, scores released**
[image: Completed and released]

---

**Quiz completed, scores released BUT post-release edits**

[image: Quiz completed score released]

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not see the button. I am on macOS 10.15.5 using Safari and I just see "Updates made after release", not the button. The quiz settings are set not to allow answers afterwards.

Comment: It's not a question of the respondents correcting their answers. It's the marker/person-who-set-the-quiz/teachers who can alter one or more questions globally and/or the points attaching to those questions, OR alter the one or more questions/marks for a specific student. In the later case, it's not a matter of changing an answer but of allowing that an specific answer which was previously a fail is acceptable (or vice versa) and/or adjusting the points for that answer. I'm using Win7 and Chrome. Would you please take a screenshot and add it to your question so we can see what you are seeing.

Comment: Sure, I will edit the question ASAP. In the meantime, could you tell me how to configure my form/quiz so that I do not get this? Thanks!

Comment: _could you tell me how to configure my form/quiz so that I do not get this?_ If this was just a simple cade of "do this and it'll be OK", I would have told you already; but you are looking for a "silver bullet" where one does not exist. Has this ever happened to you or other teachers before? What changes were made to warrant the "Updates made after release" message? What are settings apply for this quiz? Have you tried a browser other than Safari? Have you tried a computer other than a Mac?

Comment: Question edited as requested, which pictures. From your explanation it seems that I (the marker) made updates to the question or to the answer after releasing the score but without the button I could not release the score. 
It happens to me many times and I cannot figure out why, but it is not always so I could not pinpoint the cause. Also even if notifications are turned on, I almost never get them.
As said, no voluntary changes were made to cause that message. Not tried on another browser or another computer as if it worked once it should be possible for it to work consistently.

Comment: Have you hidden the email address for the respondent? it is not visible, but it should be.

Comment: No I haven't ... this also happens sometimes when the name of the person completing the quiz, which is part of my Classroom, is identified as Response 1 (or 2, or whatever).
Just to know: am I able to hide the email address of the respondent? If so, how?

Comment: _am I able to hide the email address of the respondent?_ I don't know but it shouldn't say "Response 1", it should show the email address of the respondent. Could it be that the the button is not showing, because you don't have an email address for this respondent. Also, you only have one respondent, enter some replies using your own email address and see what happens. At present, it appears as though you submitted this question on the strength of a single test reply, and haven't done any further work to establish whether this is a pattern or a one off result.